# glib.h make error. fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, make, glib

for solution i searched on the Internet.
i added the output of the command
**`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`**
that is ***`-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include`*** to the make file like 
*GCC = -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0*

```
but still an error glib.h: No such file or directory
```

here is my make file

```
ROOTDIR = $(CURDIR)
#-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  include makefiles/platforms.mk

ZLIBDIRS = zlibrary/core zlibrary/text zlibrary/ui APPDIRS = fbreader  GCC = -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0
#gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
#gcc pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0  all:  @for dir in $(ZLIBDIRS) $(APPDIRS); do \        if [ -d $$dir ]; then \             cd $$dir; \             if ! $(MAKE); then \
                exit 1; \           fi; \           cd $(ROOTDIR); \        fi; \   done;

install: all do_install

do_install:     @for dir in $(ZLIBDIRS) $(APPDIRS); do \        if [ -d $$dir ]; then \             cd $$dir; make $@; cd $(ROOTDIR); \         fi; \   done

do_install_dev:     @for dir in $(ZLIBDIRS); do \       if [ -d $$dir ]; then \             cd $$dir; make $@; cd $(ROOTDIR); \         fi; \   done

clean:  @for dir in $(ZLIBDIRS) $(APPDIRS); do \        if [ -d $$dir ]; then \             cd $$dir; make $@; cd $(ROOTDIR); \         fi; \   done

distclean: clean    @rm -rvf *.tgz *.tar.gz *.ipk *.deb *.prc *.exe
*.log *.dsc *.changes *.rpm     @rm -rf tmp packages packages-nonGPL fbreader-*
```

please get me out of this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may probably just need the -dev package containing `glib.h`: [libglib2.0-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=glib.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com and its *Search the contents of packages* form can help finding such development packages when you only know the header filename.

Comment: ya thanx i solved it...

Comment: can you please tell me how to make install in a user mode. it says permission denied  like this :  cannot remove `/usr/share/zlibrary/encodings/Big5': Permission denied

Comment: to find from the command-line: `apt-file find /glib.h`